# .htaccess Rewrite rules for unknown subfolders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i face the following problem:

My folder structure in the server is: **public_html/projects/**

Tree view: [folder structrure tree view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3i50q.png)

In the **public_html** folder there is an **.htaccess** file.

Inside the **projects** folder my partners will create numerus folders with a landing page inside (let's say just an index.php file)

The rewrite rules that i try to apply is a **language** and a **currency** url parameters.

---

So, for example
this url:
https://www.example.com/projects/whatever-project-name/index.php?lang=en&currency=eur

has to be translated to:
https://www.example.com/projects/whatever-project-name/en/eur/

Also, the currency variable is optional. (The language variable is a mandatory variable)

So the urls may be something like this too: https://www.example.com/projects/whatever-project-name/en/

---

I'm searching and trying (and crying) a couple of days now in order to solve this problem. The only one solutions that is close to mine is this:
[RewriteRule for unknown directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34877605/rewriterule-for-unknown-directory)

but i didn't manage to make it work.

What i have till now (but it doesn't work properly) is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?/([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,3})/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ projects/$1index.php?lang=$2&currency=$3
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?/([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,3})/?$ projects/$1index.php?lang=$2[L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following. Please make sure you clear your cache of browser before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##With currency variable in URI.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/projects/([\w-]+)/en/([\w-]+)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ projects/%1/index.php?lang=en&currency=%2 [L]

##Without currency variable in URI.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/projects/([\w-]+)/en/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ projects/%1/index.php?lang=en [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response!
I have just tryied your solution but i get an Internal Server Error page

Comment: @GregVlachokostas, Sorry had a typo `)` was missing in 1st rule, could you please try edited ones once and let me know then how it goes then?